# How to adding image item to RecyclerView using a button without internet?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use a adding button to get the photo from the gallery and put it to RecyclerView with text. When the user selected image form the gallery, the application will return the image path, but now, I no idea how to use the path to get the image and put it to RecyclerView to display with text, here is my coding:

```
 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     try {
         if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                 && null != data) {

             Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Yor are picked image from" + selectedImage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         } else {
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You haven't picked image.",
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                 .show();
     }
 }
```

Sorry for my English. Thank you for help.

[Here is my adding button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYchN.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your adapter class you have to implement add method, something like this:

```
public void addImage(String imagePath) {
    imagesPaths.add(imagePath);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

notifyDataSetChanged() is crucial, because it calls for update on RecyclerView.

So in your onActivityResult you just have to pass image path to adapter:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            // Here you pass image path
            yourAdapter.add(selectedImage.toString());


            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Yor are picked image from" + selectedImage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You haven't picked image.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
```